# DescribeImagesRequest by name aws java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Could someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong in this ?

```
 final AmazonEC2 ec2 = getEC2Client();
    DescribeImagesRequest describeImagesRequest = new DescribeImagesRequest();
    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.setName("name");
    filter.setValues(Arrays.asList("test-latest-amis12"));
    describeImagesRequest.withFilters(filter);
    DescribeImagesResult result = ec2.describeImages(describeImagesRequest);
    for(Image images :result.getImages()){
        System.out.println(images.getImageId());
    }
```

I am trying to fetch the ami by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using actual name in the value.

name in documentation is actually the second column which is ami name.

```
          Name                      AMI Name
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        test-latest-amis12   Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Java 8
```